# Hubot CronJob Function

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, cron, hubot

Cant seem to figure out how to achieve this. I am trying to make Hubot call a function periodically in a specific hipchat channel.

Currently I am able to do this by having the user type in chat "Hubot totalviewers" and hubot will return with the number of current viewers. The point is to have hubot do this by itself without having the user type the command (happen every minute).

Any documentation, examples or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) for that

Example:
https://leanpub.com/automation-and-monitoring-with-hubot/read#leanpub-auto-periodic-task-execution

Answer (score 0):

You could use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval)? This should be feasible when [scripting with Hubot](https://github.com/github/hubot/blob/master/docs/scripting.md).

Something like...

```
setInterval ->
    do totalviewers
, 60000 # 1 minute
```